# I get a warning when I try to run my C++ program

Tags: c++

I am a new programmer. I get a warning when I run my program in an online editor; the warning is

> 'number' is used uninitialized in this function [-wuninitialized]".

We used eclipse, which it does not show me this error. But in both I get a number when I run the program.

My code:

```
double number;
cout << "enter a number: " << number;
cin >> number;
```

I get this when I run it:

**enter a number: 0** or **2.122e-314**

but this 0 or 2.12... does not affect the rest of the program!

Answer (score 2):

You are writing an uninitialized variable to `std::cout` in the line

```
cout << "enter a number: " << number;
```

That explains the warning and the output. You need to change it to:

```
cout << "enter a number: ";
```

After you read the number, you can use:

```
cout << "The number you entered: " << number;
```

---

```
double number;
cout << "enter a number: ";
cin >> number;
cout << "The number you entered: " << number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is:

```
double number;
cout << "enter a number: " << number;
cin >> number;
```

1.First you declared a variable `number`.

2.After that when you use `cout<<number` it will print the value which is variable holding.
here the `number` is just declared.
the `number` is holding nothing so it will print some random value.

3.first you have to put some value into a variable then you can print.
so corrected code will be:

```
double number;
cin >> number;
cout << "number you entered : " << number;
```